# Facing an issue with FAISS in langchain

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, langchain, google-cloud-vertex-ai, faiss

Hi I'm trying to create a FAISS object and facing an issue - `AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo' object has no attribute 'WhichOneof'` in the last line "db = ..."

Also this is how I am doing it -

```
class MyVertexAIEmbeddings(VertexAIEmbeddings, Embeddings):
    model_name = 'textembedding-gecko'
    max_batch_size = 5
    
    def embed_segments(self, segments: List) -> List:
        embeddings = []
        for i in tqdm(range(0, len(segments), self.max_batch_size)):
            batch = segments[i: i+self.max_batch_size]
            embeddings.extend(self.client.get_embeddings(batch))
        return [embedding.values for embedding in embeddings]
    
    def embed_query(self, query: str) -> List:
        embeddings = self.client.get_embeddings([query])
        return embeddings[0].values
```

```
documents = JSONLoader(file_path='./data/rag-schema/tables.jsonl', jq_schema='.', text_content=False, json_lines=True).load()
embedding = MyVertexAIEmbeddings()
```

```
db = FAISS.from_documents(documents=documents, embedding=embedding)
```

Trying to get a resolution of my issue.